# convert list to list of list and take the length of nested list from another list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list like this:

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,23,32,33] 
l2=[5,3,1,2]
```

I want the final list be look like

```
l3=[[1,2,3,4,5],[7,8,9],[23],[32,33]]
```

The length of each nested list will come form l2,

How to do it in efficient way using python.

Comment: Is it given that the sum of all elements in `I2` equal to the length of the list `l1`?

Comment: Also, what have you done so far? Share your progress, at least?

Answer (score 4):

You could create an iterator and then create the nested lists:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> l1=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,23,32,33] 
>>> l2=[5,3,1,2]
>>> it = iter(l1)
>>> [list(islice(it, n)) for n in l2]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [23], [32, 33]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import repeat, islice
# itertools works with iterators, so we'll make one
itl1 = iter(l1)
```

And now if you want a lazy result:

```
lazy = map(islice, repeat(itl1), l2)
```

If you want a realized result:

```
realized = list(map(list, lazy))
```

The point is that `islice` depletes the iterator `itl1` by the amounts stated in `l2` in every step of the `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a comprehension:

```
>>> l3 = [[l1.pop(0) for _ in range(x)] for x in l2]
>>> l3
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [23], [32, 33]]
```

If you dont want to modify l1, use an iterator:

```
>>> l1=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,23,32,33] 
>>> it = iter(l1)
>>> l3 = [[next(it) for _ in range(x)] for x in l2]
>>> l3
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [23], [32, 33]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) and `pairwise`, the latter a recipe [available in the `itertools` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) or available in 3rd party [`more_itertools.pairwise`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.pairwise):

```
from itertools import accumulate
from more_itertools import pairwise

L1 = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,23,32,33] 
L2 = [5,3,1,2]

L3 = [L1[i: j] for i, j in pairwise(accumulate([0] + L2))]

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [23], [32, 33]]
```